# Linux Module file missing

Tags: linux, kernel-module, parallel-port

Actually I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn the concept of low-level driver and high level driver. I want to know how a module depends on other modules for their operation.

I've done `lsmod` command. I found these lines in the output.

```
parport_pc             25962  1 
lp                      7028  0 
parport                32635  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
```

From the above lines, I understood that there exist modules like,

> - parport_pc
> - lp
> - parport

I've found source code `parport_pc.c`, `lp.c`, in the directory `/usr/src/drivers/parport`. But I can't find the source code for `parport` in my entire file system. Even though I found `parpot.ko` inside `/lib/modules/linux2.6.32-37-generic/kernel/parport`. 
Also in the directory `/usr/src/drivers/parport`, I've seen a line in the Makefile like,

```
obj-$(CONFIG_PARPORT)       += parport.o
```

So where can I find the `parport.c` file ? I've searched the entire file system using the command

```
find / -name parport.c
```

but no result. Why is the file `parport.c` missing?

Comment: A `.c` file is generally a file of uncompiled c. You probably don't have the uncompiled source code for your OS on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

The `parport.o` file is compiled from multiple `.c` files, including `share.c`, `ieee1284.c`, `ieee1284_ops.c`, and `procfs.c`, and possibly including `daisy.c` and `probe.c`, all under the `drivers/parport/` directory of the Linux sources. (This information was taken from Linux 3.5-rc3-00203-g8874e81, which is a bit newer than the kernel you are looking at, but the parallel port drivers don't change much any more).

To find this information, I looked at the same `Makefile` and noted that the `parport-objs` variable was initially set to `share.o ieee1284.o ieee1284_ops.o procfs.o` and `daisy.o probe.o` was added if `CONFIG_PARPORT_1284` was set to `y`.